# z/OS COBOL V6 calling a DLL

Tags: dll, dllimport, cobol, zos

I am primarily a C developer. I have a sample COBOL driver that calls my C DLL in z/OS.

The COBOL driver was working fine in z/OS COBOL V4 when we used the Pre-Linker and IMPORT statements to define the API’s inside the DLL.

With COBOL V6 (and V5), the pre-linker is no longer supported (along with a myriad of other changes).

How can I get COBOL to recognize my IMPORT statements to know about the LONGMIXED API’s inside my DLL?

The COBOL call looks like:

```
CALL
  'PBFNTerminate' USING
                    BY VALUE NULL-POINTER,
```

My COBOL program is compiled with `RENT,DLL,PGMN(LM)`.

I tried to simply include the IMPORT statements from the DLL creation in the BINDER but they seem to be ignored. I have `DYNAM(DLL),CALL` as a BINDER parameter but I still get:

```
IEW2456E 9207 SYMBOL PBFNTerminate UNRESOLVED.  MEMBER COULD NOT BE INCLUDED FROM THE DESIGNATED CALL LIBRARY.
```

If I run the BINDER with `DYNAM(DLL),NCAL`  I get

```
IEW2454W 9203 SYMBOL PBFNTerminate UNRESOLVED.  NO AUTOCALL (NCAL) SPECIFIED.  NAME SPACE = 3
```

And then a S0C1 when I try to run.
I’m thinking there is a step or parameter I’m missing but obviously I don’t know what it is.

Side comment, the COBOL INTERLANGUAGE COMMUNICATIONS guide seems to be written pre COBOL V5 and V6: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos/4.2?topic=answers-interlanguage-communication

Comment: `CALL`/`NCAL` should not be relevant in your case, since the call is meant to be dynamic anyway. The Binder should be able to do anything the Prelinker did, so it seems like some parameter is not det right. We don't use dlls in our shop, but could you include the complete binder output? Maybe there's some additional hints in there...

Comment: Found the problem. At least for me, the PLKED step defaulted NOUPCASE. In the Binder I had to add CASE(MIXED) to the PARM. The the final solution was: PGM=HEWL,PARM='DYNAM(DLL),CASE(MIXED)'.

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem. At least for me, the PLKED step defaulted NOUPCASE. In the Binder I had to add CASE(MIXED) to the PARM. The the final solution was: **PGM=HEWL,PARM='DYNAM(DLL),CASE(MIXED)'**.